# How to prevent files, assets, folders,being bundled by rollup?

Tags: vite, rollup, rollupjs

I am using vite to build a component library, I have some set of folders inside src/components and some folders inside the public that needs to be ignored from the rollup output bundle. I cant find an option to ignore them in rollupOptions.

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    libInjectCss(),
    react(),
    dts({
      include: [
        "src/components/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
        "src/transport-icons/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
      ],
      exclude: ["**/*.stories.tsx"],

      beforeWriteFile: (filePath, content) => {
        if (
          filePath.includes("dist-storybook") ||
          filePath.includes(".stories.d.ts") ||
          filePath.includes("transport-icons")
        ) {
          return { filePath, content };
        }
        const [projectPath, chunkPath] = filePath.split("/dist/");
        const chunk = chunkPath?.split("/").pop();
        return { filePath: `${projectPath}/dist/${chunk}`, content };
      },
    }),
  ],

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  },
  build: {
    cssCodeSplit: true,
    lib: {
      formats: ["es"],
      entry: [],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      
      input: {
        ...componentEntries,
        GlobalCss: "./src/components/global.css",
      },

      external: ["react", "react-dom", "react/jsx-runtime"],
      output: {
        assetFileNames: (chunk) => {
          return `${camelCase(chunk.name)}`;
        },

        globals: {
          react: "React",
          "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
          "react/jsx-runtime": "react/jsx-runtime",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I have managed to give only the specific entry files in`componentEntries` ignore some folders using a js filter function but everything in public folder is in the bundle.How to ignore files and folders properly in rollup.js ?